# printf alignment for multiple format specifiers

Tags: c, alignment, printf

How can I align say the following piece of text using printf function
Say I wanted the desired output of

```
void print() {
   printf("%s %s     %d     %c\n",firstName, lastName, age, gender); 
}
```

to be:

```
Foo Foo     15     M

Bob Bob     16     F

John John    12     M
```

The problem I am having is since the name John is longer, it will push the next specifier down a bit. I want them to be aligned so each line is in order.

Comment: @xing can you explain? why did you pick these numbers?

Comment: @xing ok i got it thank you

Answer (score 0):

Copy the first and last name into a temporary string.  Then pass that to `printf`, using a field width on `%s` large enough to fit a full name with the `-` flag to left-justify.

```
void print(char *first, char *last, int age, char gender)
{
    int len = strlen(first) + strlen(last) + 1;
    char name[len+1];
    strcpy(name, first);
    strcat(name, " ");
    strcat(name, last);
    printf("%-20s %2d    %c\n",name, age, gender);
}
```

With your sample input, this outputs:

```
Foo Foo              15    M
Bob Bob              16    F
John John            12    M
```